# nginx location block if directive (query parameter match for pimcore_editmode=true)

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, pimcore

I have a localized website built on frontend vue/nuxt2 (own docker container) and pimcore (as backend cms, with own docker container).

The nginx location rules are defined in the pimcore docker container and work for all the routes, with this being the location rule:

```
location ~* "^/[a-z]{2}/?$" { #matches language codes 'en', 'de', etc
    # $nuxt_supported defined by script including this file (is true)
    if ($nuxt_supported = 1) {
        return 418;
    }
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}
```

For the homepage I am having the following issue:
The route works for nuxt (loads the homepage fine, pages/index.vue template), however, in the pimcore admin area, when I try and open the 'en' (localized english) document, it is ALSO hitting the nuxt server which is unwanted, it should just hit pimcore cms directly
(in this case the URL is something like localhost:8000/en?pimcore_editmode=true&systemLocale=en&_dc=1693920281464 )

So I have tried the following, to mimic an if-else condition (according to [here](https://onelinerhub.com/nginx/using-if-else-condition)).

```
location ~* "^/[a-z]{2}/?$" { # location regex ignores GET query params (only uses base URL)
    set $is_nuxt_supported $nuxt_supported;

    # if pimcore admin mode, don't use nuxt
    if ($arg_pimcore_editmode = 'true') {
        set $is_nuxt_supported 0;
    }

    if ($is_nuxt_supported = 1) {
        return 418;
    }

    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}
```

However, now the url with ?pimcore_editmode=true (ie pimcore admin area), returns a 404 (the frontend homepage still works, but not this admin page):

[image: nginx 404]

I noticed the docker container output logs (nginx) is giving following error:

> 2023/09/06 14:20:28 [error] 618#618: *47 open()
> "/var/www/mysite.com/web/en" failed (2: No such file or directory),
> client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /en?pimcore_editmode=true
> HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"

The path /var/www/mysite.com/web/en doesn't exist on the container, the correct path is without the 'en': "/var/www/mysite.com/web"

OK so that makes me think the $uri in the try_files directive is incorrect (shouldn't have '/en' in it. So I tried the following:

```
location ~* "^/[a-z]{2}/?$" { # location regex ignores GET query params (only uses base URL)
    set $is_nuxt_supported $nuxt_supported;
    set $try_path $uri;

    # if pimcore admin mode, don't use nuxt
    if ($args ~ "pimcore_editmode=true") {
        set $is_nuxt_supported 0;
        set $try_path "";
    }

    if ($is_nuxt_supported = 1) {
        return 418;
    }

    add_header X-tryPath "$try_path" always; #add_header not working now, worked for X-uri!

    try_files $try_path /app.php$is_args$args;
}
```

But alas still not working (same error).

Apparently getting nginx if to work as expected is difficult:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Any help much appreciated,
G